# How can I write general TypeGuard for GraphQL unions?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write one-size-fits-all Type Guard for GraphQL unions.

Let's say we have two types A and B, and C is the union type of them.
A has a property `a` but B doesn't.
I think it can be useful if we could have a type guard like this:

`xs.filter(isTypename("a")).map(x => x.a)`

I tried a while but I still didn't complete.

Is it able to be achieved?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIPp5gCeADhCHALYQBcyARHPQNw7Jx0DOYUoA5qwC+WUJFiIUAIUxsCxMhWp16AIxZsVXHvyFYs8lAGFkAXjTIAPskmt9pKXE4ozGYVggAPEgHsoYZAjeINzIwJwAKvaKzsgAPOHInpAgACacyNy8IHwANMgAct4pEAlJ5GmYclFUtBna2YIAfAAUbAbRdOFYAJSmjcjNIEW1hcXh3XRDxaHpAPKUwGCxoyV59FUKNfT9AGSY+ITVSsgJgn0yuFAQYACuUCDIUxAAdBvkNaYmZu01QraBwX8Hk4dEMAG0ALqmZBgjAHH7HRj0PIcBhMZCCPJwt4dBhqPKaPH0DEQ-5BEJETgARmhwOeMGAABsxM0wpFNtRmkjut1npQ4CRmh5zh5nnBuqwgA

```
interface A {
  __typename: "a";
  a: string;
}
interface B {
  __typename: "b";
  b: string;
}

type C = A | B;

type Base = {}

export const isTypename = <T extends string, NodeT extends {__typename: string}>(
  typename: T
) => (node: NodeT): node is Omit<NodeT, "__typename"> & { __typename: T } => {
  return node.__typename === typename;
};

const xs: C[] = [{ __typename: "a", a: "a" }, { __typename: "b", b: "b" }];

const ys1 = xs.filter(isTypename("a")).map(x => x.a);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think if you expect to be using [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) types, then you will get better behavior if your user-defined type guard returns a type like `val is Extract<DiscriminatedUnionType, {discriminant: LiteralDiscriminant}>` instead of intersections like `val is DiscriminatedUnionType & {discriminant: LiteralDiscriminant}` (or the one with `Omit<DiscriminatedUnionType , "discriminant"> & {discriminant: LiteralDiscriminant}`, which won't even compile because the compiler [can't verify that it's a subtype](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26548) of `DiscriminatedUnionType`).

**UPDATE FOR TS3.9+**: the above issue with intersections has been improved greatly in TS3.9.  Now, [intersections are reduced by discriminant properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#36696](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696)), so `val is DiscriminatedUnionType & {discriminant: LiteralDiscriminant}` will now eliminate incompatible types from the discriminated union.  I still recommend using `Extract` instead, though, because the output is simpler and doesn't carry around the intersection. **END UPDATE**

`Extract<T, U>` is a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) that uses a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to filter unions.  Hypothetically, intersections could be made to do the same thing, but in TypeScript [intersections of disjoint object types do not reduce to `never`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13203).  So while `{foo: "a", a: string} & {foo: "b"}` is *equivalent* to `never` (you'll never get a value of that type), the compiler does not actually *reduce* it to `never`.  On the other hand, `Extract<{foo: "a", a: string}, {foo: "b"}>` *will* produce `never`.  And you need that reduction, since `X | never` reduces to `X`.

---

So let's try the following version of the type guard:

```
const isTypename = <T extends string>(typename: T) => <
  N extends { __typename: string }
>(
  node: N
): node is Extract<N, { __typename: T }> => {
  return node.__typename === typename;
};
```

in which the return type predicate uses `Extract`.

Note that I also moved the generic `N` (your `NodeT`) to the signature of the returned function.  That should help with type inference. The call `isTypeName("a")` by itself has no obvious inference site for `N`.  If I did

```
const filterCb = isTypename("a"); 
xs.filter(filterCb);
```

Your version would end up having `N` inferred as `{ __typename: string }` instead of as `C`, and unfortunately the return type would be `node is never` instead of `node is A`, which would be a problem.

Sometimes [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) can save you, so

```
xs.filter(isTypename("a"));
```

might be enough contextual type to infer `N` as `C` and everything would be great.  But generally I'd like `isTypeName("a")` to return a generic function in which `N` is definitely not going to be prematurely resolved.

---

Okay, let's see if it works:

```
const ys1 = xs.filter(isTypename("a")).map(x => x.a); // string[]
```

Looks good!  Hope that helps.  Good luck.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIPp5gCeADhCHALYQBcyARHPQNw7Jx0DOYUoA5qwC+WUJFiIUAIUxsCxMhWp16AIxZsVXHvyFYs8lAGFkAXjTIAPskmssCAPYhuyYJwAqpclRRmAPG+QIAA9IEAATTmRuXhA+AD4ACgNFWmQ3AEpTOORfNgA5QJDyCMx8Qk8UrRi+ZGFEthB7MNS8rHS6RuaXSIBREKhEMF88gBpSuQrvOgDBbJNs7FwoCDAAVygQZE6IADoJhW9TEzNk7yFbBycwZCDOOkMAbQBdU2QHjDLTpQYmMY4f+i1MYffZeb6qehjTQMNS1J4XRzOGDAAA2YkMKlerg8B2oCUY9HSzGQAHoScg+ORoMAEMgYCAsLcdsi0dAEiz0SoiaTyahnnpLs4iJwAIyvJkctnYyZ4gnpdI7ShwEgJIJZG47ODcslRbSxflAA)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! It really helps me a lot!

Comment: this is really awesome. I already an auto generated schema from postgraphile and and auto-generated types from queries by graphql-codegenerator. So I want to get rid of writing boilerplate code for common CRUD like `useLogin()`, `useCurrentUser()`.
I want to build something where I can just write `const {login }= useMutation<AutoGenerated.Login>(); login(user,pw);`. I think this will help a lot in dynamically asserting types via `__typename`.

Comment: I had problem matching interfaces where typename is a list of implementors: `__typename: 'TypeA' | 'TypeB'`. Using `&` instead of `Extract` resolved the issue.